# Editing the iPhone Simulator hosts file

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

is it possible to edit the hosts file of the iPhone simulator?

I'm working on a REST API and I need to be able to access my local site using a correct domain (e.g. http://api.local.com)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can simply edit your Mac's `/etc/hosts` file and iPhone Simulator will adopt whatever is set there.

It works because the iPhone Simulator simply provides a simulated frontend of Mobile Safari's user interface, which just uses your Mac's network settings.

Comment: There is some [indication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973476/xcode-6-simulator-ignores-hosts-file-changes) that this behaviour has changed with the Xcode 6 iOS Simulator.  Do you know anything about it BoltClock?

Comment: @trojanfoe: Hmm, I don't think so :( I haven't had a chance to update to Xcode 6 yet.

Comment: It's not clear how the simulator would even work if it didn't rely on the OSX name resolution subsystem, so it could very well be a red herring.  Anyway, cheers.

Comment: I'm currently working on a project with Xcode 6 and editing /etc/hosts of host OSX doesn't seem to affect iOS Simulator.

Here is a link to same issue with Xcode 6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973476/xcode-6-simulator-ignores-hosts-file-changes

Comment: I would love if Android simulator works the same way (it is not)