# iOS 8 / Xcode 6 Simulator is not using HTTP Proxy anymore

Tags: proxy, ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6, charles-proxy

My iOS 8 Simulator is not using my proxy settings anymore (I want to debug with Charles). The rest of the system does. The simulator somehow seems to get direct internet access. Have I missed some new setting?

Caution: this is NO dup of [How to use Charles Proxy on the Xcode 6 (iOS 8) Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439756/how-to-use-charles-proxy-on-the-xcode-6-ios-8-simulator). I´m not trying to use SSL on the simulator in the first place. My simulator doesn´t even start to use the proxy.

### Charles:

[image: Proxy Settings]

### System:

[image: Connection]
[image: Proxy Settings]

Comment: iPhone simulator always uses the network settings of your mac. Check if your machine is connected with both ethernet and wifi at same time. try switching off 1 of the network connection and than check again.

Comment: It´s only connected via Ethernet and only on this connection the proxy is set.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not an issue with simulator but with your network settings than.. Check properly if network is properly configured to use the proxy settings only..

Comment: I updated my question with screenshots, please see above.

Comment: Simply restart the iPhone simulator.

for this i use the following trick

go to setting >> General >> Accessibility >> bold text to switch on >> picker view open and ask for restart for make it effective >> press continue >> iPhone simulator now restart

the pop-up ask for user name and password for proxy. (suggested by someone else on internet)

Comment: @Dinesh: Thanks, but doesn´t work for me. Further, I don´t need authentication for my proxy.

Comment: @stk: Have you resolved this issue? I am also facing same issue. I am able to access the URL in Mac Browser, but when trying to access the same inside ioS Simulator safari i could not connect with server. Any idea? I did restart and reset simulator. nothing helped me.

Comment: For me the selected right answer did work...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Restart the simulator between proxy changes

Comment: Or any network configuration change, not just for proxy changes.

Comment: Why do I have to come here to restart my Simulator? "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" is what we should always ask ourselves first! :-) Thanks for reminding me! Saved my day.

Comment: Also starting a new session may help in Charles

Answer (score 5):

This is correct.  Proxy settings that are setup on the host are not necessarily usable by the simulated runtime.  If your proxy server requires authentication, you will not be able to use it in the iOS Simulator due to the simulator and host not sharing the same keychain.  If you rely on this functionality, please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and request an alternative.

Also note that this is discussed in the [Xcode 6 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html):

> - iOS Simulator does not support the use of network proxy servers that    require authentication. (14889876)

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget the HTTPS:

1. Set **Web Proxy (HTTP)** and **Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS)**
2. Restart the simulator after proxy changes