# Web Service accessible by most browsers but Safari and iOS app

Tags: ios, wcf, sharepoint, safari

A short version of my current problem:

Our service 
https://staging.apps.wv.gov/dhhr/cjtf/HelpMeWV/api/contacts
is accessible in Windows browsers, android app, Chrome in Mac, but not accessible in iOS app, Safari, or Chrome in iOS.

```
error Code: WebException
message: The remote name could not be resolved: ‘wwwnew.wv.gov’.
```

Some more detailed info:

**HelpMeWV** is a .NET application translating SharePoint wcf service (http://wwwnew.wv.gov/services/HelpMeWV/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata) into RESTful API using **ServiceStack**. Here **wwwnew.wv.gov** is parsed in the **hosts** file on my staging server.

I would assume a web browser visiting the .NET REST API would have no need to be aware of the location of SharePoint service. Further, if my Android app and other browsers to access the API and obtain data, there is no reason a Safari or an iOS app cannot visit.

---

I have added the **wwwnew.wv.gov** entry to my Mac's **hosts** file. Still get the same error.

Comment: possibily related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973476/xcode-6-simulator-ignores-hosts-file-changes

Comment: simulator or a real device?